# Poner filtro en la creación de Pivot Table en App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, filtro, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica, tabla-dinámica

Tengo este código que trabaja muy bien para crear una Pivot Table, no sé como ni en qué parte de este código poner un filtro que tome en cuenta solo los renglones que en la columna X contenga `"Juan Pérez"`, por ejemplo.

```
function createPivotTable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // The name of the sheet containing the data you want to put in a table.
  var sheetName = "LFM-Comisiones";

  var pivotTableParams = {};

  // The source indicates the range of data you want to put in the table.
  // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
  pivotTableParams.source = {
    sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId()
  };

  // Group rows, the 'sourceColumnOffset' corresponds to the column number in the source range
  // eg: 0 to group by the first column
  pivotTableParams.rows =[{
                    "sourceColumnOffset": 14,
                    "showTotals": true,
                    "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                    "valueBucket": {
                      "buckets": [
                        {
                          "stringValue": "West"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "sourceColumnOffset": 1,
                    "showTotals": false,
                    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                    "valueBucket": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "sourceColumnOffset": 2,
                    "showTotals": false,
                    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                    "valueBucket": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "sourceColumnOffset": 3,
                    "showTotals": false,
                    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                    "valueBucket": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "sourceColumnOffset": 4,
                    "showTotals": false,
                    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                    "valueBucket": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "sourceColumnOffset": 10,
                    "showTotals": false,
                    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                    "valueBucket": {}
                  }
                ];
  //pivotTableParams.visibleValues=[];

  // Defines how a value in a pivot table should be calculated.
  pivotTableParams.values = [{
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 8
  }];

   pivotTableParams.criteria = [{
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 8
  }];


  // Create a new sheet which will contain our Pivot Table
  var pivotTableSheet = ss.insertSheet();
  var pivotTableSheetId = pivotTableSheet.getSheetId();

  // Add Pivot Table to new sheet
  // Meaning we send an 'updateCells' request to the Sheets API
  // Specifying via 'start' the sheet where we want to place our Pivot Table
  // And in 'rows' the parameters of our Pivot Table
  var request = {
    "updateCells": {
      "rows": {
        "values": [{
          "pivotTable": pivotTableParams
        }]
      },
      "start": {
        "sheetId": pivotTableSheetId
      },
      "fields": "pivotTable"
    }
  };
```

Comment: Esta semana se agregaron nuevos métodos y clases en Google Apps Script incluyendo algunos para manejar tablas dinámicas y así como agregar y editar filtros en estas. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-filter#setFilterCriteria(FilterCriteria)

Answer (score 0):

Por los comentarios incluídos en el código, el código original pareciera que fue tomado de [Create & update Pivot Tables](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/pivot).

Analizando más a detalle tu código, copiaste

```
pivotTableParams.values = [{
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 8
  }];
```

y luego lo pegaste como

```
pivotTableParams.criteria = [{
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 8
  }];
```

reemplazando `values` por `criteria`, pero dejaste las mismas propiedades. Ahí es donde estuvo tu error. En lugar de

```
[{
  summarizeFunction: "SUM",
  sourceColumnOffset: 8
}];
```

debería haber sido algo con la sintaxis siguiente

```
string: {
     object(PivotFilterCriteria)
}
```

donde `string` es el índice de la columna de fuente de datos. Por ejemplo, si la fuente de datos fuera C10:F50, la columna C tendría el índice 0, la columna D el índice 1 y así sucesivamente.

En cuanto a `object(PivotFilterCriteria)`, éste tiene la sintaxis siguiente

```
{
  "visibleValues": [
    string
  ],
}
```

Referencia

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#PivotTable

Answer (score 0):

Intenta reemplazando esta parte:

```
pivotTableParams.criteria = [{
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
    sourceColumnOffset: 8
}];
```

Por esto otro:

```
pivotTableParams.criteria = {
    <columnIndex>:{"visibleValues": ['Value1','Value2']}  
};
```

O sea, si los nombres están en la columna 5, tu código deberia ser:

```
pivotTableParams.criteria = {
    5:{"visibleValues": ['Juan Perez','Maria Lopez']}  
};
```

¡Espero que te sirva!